# Google cloud container cluster environmental variables for secrets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am having really hard time figuring out how I am supposed to store secrets like keys, passwords etc. in google container cluster. I would like to use environmental variables for that if possible. What is the best approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Kubernetes [secret](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/secrets/) object: "Secrets can be mounted as data volumes or be exposed as environment variables to be used by a container in a pod."